# How to do module argumentation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I have the following code in Node Js:

```
var xtend=require('xtend');
var d=function(options){
          options=xtend({
                text:' ',
                style: ' '
          }, options);
     };
```

I want to do the similar thing in normal JS but couldn't figure out. 
Can anyone please help me how to do similar functionality in Js.
I'm trying to make a module in js.

Comment: Node.js is normal JS. Have you tried reading the source code of `xtend`? It's really trivial (i.e. about 10 lines long).

Comment: Exactly what @Quentin said. To add to that, you could use the spread operator "...".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, your question is how to "combine" two objects without using an additional library? This can be done in several ways:

```
const options = { foo: 'bar' };
const stuff = { text:' ', style: ' ' };
```

The "old" way with [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
const test1 = Object.assign(options, stuff);
```

Or with the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for object literals in ES6:

```
const test2 = { ...options, ...stuff };
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0195qzdx/

Please use the documentation for detailed answers.